# Having an error in a code and couldn't fix it ? android list,

Tags: java, android

I used this code in this website until 1.3 :

### http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

1.4. Listener

To react to selections in the list set an OnItemClickListener to your ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
});
```

---

I copied this code to the main activity but an error comes in this line :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

note: actually I didn't understand step 1.3 ...I'm beginner in Java language..

What shall I do and can anyone explain this code?

Comment: If you have an error, let's see it. Until that, we're just guessing :-)

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: an exception will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

your code is right.
for error following may be:
1. listview is not defined.
2. OnItemClickListener not imported.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this...

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Look at this.i done your example only.its worked for me.

```
 package com.list;

    import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

      public class ListActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

    // First paramenter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third parameter - ID of the View to which the data is written
    // Forth - the Array of data
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: i try it and also i have the same error, 

1.3 i dont understand it.. I just skip it,
in 1.3 should i do some code?

thank you

Comment: i will tell you what i did step by step.first, my project have 2 activities : 1-List_view_Activity that contains 1.2 and 1.4 second Activity My Simple Array Adapter contains 1.5 also i have main . XML that contain 1.1... if any one know what is wrong with my steps please help me. thank you